How to set $elements values in Laravel Slack notification block classes
I am converting a Laravel app from using Nathanhelfley/laravel-slack-blocks to using the built in Illuminate\Notifications\Slack\BlockKit\Blocks blocks, and I can't figure out how to pass in the $elements value. For instance, with a SlackBlock class, I would do this for a context block;
    $block->elements([
        [
            'type' => 'mrkdwn',
            'text' => "Pursuit: *{$this->activityModel->target->name}*",
        ],
    ]);

However, with the ContextBlock class, there is no interface to pass in the entire element (e.g. type => markdown) because there is no setter for $elements and it is protected. The same is true for the other block types. How do I pass in the other values for a block other than the text and the id?
Per one suggestion (AI) I reveived, the correct implementation is something like this
$contextBlock = new ContextBlock();
$contextBlock->text(new MarkdownText("Pursuit: *{$this->activityModel->target->name}*"));
Add the block to your Slack message:
use Illuminate\Notifications\Slack\SlackMessage;

$slackMessage = (new SlackMessage)
    ->blocks(function ($block) use ($contextBlock) {
        $block->context($contextBlock);
    });

But there are two problems

The MarkdownText class doesn't exist
the TextObject class does, and it has a markdown() setter. However, the text() method takes a string, not an object.

Something like this doesn't work, for the same reason
        $block = new ContextBlock();

        $text_block = new TextObject("Pursuit: *{'My pursuit text}*");
        $text_block->markdown();

        $block->text($text_block);

Yes, I've seen the Laravel Notifications docs, but that doesn't really answer this question, either (unless I'm missing something).
So how do I build the blocks with all of the $elements values?

There is Illuminate\Notifications\Slack\SlackMessage which is basicly builder. Altho I think it misses at least few elements, select for example.
